How to provide code coverage for open source Spark project
We forked apache spark project and wanted to provide coverage for the code using Jacoco plugin.
I was following the instructions to build and run tests for the open source Apache spark (https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master)
./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package

and then
./dev/run-tests

However the above run throws an error
[error] running /spark/dev/test-dependencies.sh ; received return code 1

I am running this on Mac with Java 17 for 3.5.0 branch. I tried to fix things, but running into another issue.
This makes me wonder how these tests are being run on Jenkins when we are cutting a new build. Or is this Mac book specific issue?
